# VueJS: no-unused-vars

Tags: html, vue.js

Tenho um código simples em VueJS e preciso importar um componente. Dei uma olhada na documentação e procurei pela internet, mas não consigo enxergar onde estou errando. 
Pelo que entendi, basta usar o nome do componente como uma tag, certo? Então porque continuo recebendo o erro de error `no-unused-vars`?

A exportação:

```html
<script>
export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
        msg: String
    }
};
</script>
```

Importação:

```js
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld"
```

E uma parte do lugar onde chamo o componente:

```html
<template>

  <div>

    <div id="slogan" class="text-center">

      <h1>NameGator <span class="fa fa-coffee"></span></h1>
      <br/>
      <h6 class="text-secondary">Gerador de nomes utilizando <kbd>Vue.JS</kbd></h6>

    </div>

    <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
```

Não quis adicionar todo o código pois ficaria extenso, e não é esse meu objetivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na seção scripts do seu código vue, você deve adicionar a chave `components`.
Da seguinte forma:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <LeadInfo></LeadInfo>
    <Container></Container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeadInfo from "@/components/LeadInfo.vue";
import Container from "@/components/Container.vue";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    LeadInfo,
    Container
  }
};
</script>
```

Assim que você adicionar este código a mensagem de erro desaparecerá.

Verifique principalmente o código que está dentro da tag `script`. Adicione a chave components, em seguida adicione o componente que deseja utilizar em seu `template`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Está certo, acabei deixando esse detalhe passar.